# Missing step in jQuery and getting "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: jquery

i have a script.js page

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//errortrap
function alerts(str) {
    return false;
}
//errortrap

//lightbox
$('.LikeDiv').lightBox({ openPop: '.rename', closePop: '.cloSign', centerAlign: true });
//lightbox
});

function lightboxopen() {

$('.LikeDiv').load('subscriberforgotpassword.aspx');
return false;
}

function showLightBox() {

$('.rename').trigger('click');
}
```

I am getting this error 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined' even after the $ is present.
can anyone tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document)` does not guarantee the fact that it is loaded. to do this, you'll need to either:

- Bind to DOM the old-school way
- Wrap a closure
- Make sure the script is loaded after jQuery (i.e. its script tag is after)

Answer (score 0):

The error is more than likely you are loading jquery after script.js.  Make sure your reference to the jquery library is loaded first.