# ReferenceError: $showExpanded is not defined, but it cleary is

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, referenceerror

Hey guys i've done some research on [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855590/referenceerror-is-not-defined) questions and i tried the given solutions but i still don't get why it doesn't work.
Everyone says that you have to use the `document ready`-function.
And now some solutions say that i have to remove it?
I don't really see a problem with the code.

[image: Error]

Could someone explain clearly to me why this isn't working? I'm so curious. Thanks for the efforts.

here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#expandSearch').css('display', 'none');
  $('#easySearch').css('display', 'block');

  function showExpanded(){
    $('#expandSearch').css('display', 'block');
    $('#easySearch').css('display', 'none');
  }

  function removeExpanded(){
    $('#expandSearch').css('display', 'none');
    $('#easySearch').css('display', 'block');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="easySearch">
  easySearch
  <p onclick="showExpanded">Show expanded</p>
</div>
<div id="expandSearch">
  expandSearch
  <p onclick="removeExpanded">Remove expanded</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont see any error in demo

Comment: the snippet works perfectly as regards jQuery. `onclick="showExpanded"` should be `onclick="showExpanded()"` though. There must be some other problem with your original code. Check your console / network tab to see if the jquery.min.js file is definitely loading successfully.

Comment: The error means that jQuery isn't available at the point you're attempting to use it. If you have included jquery.js, then it means you've put it too late in the page

Comment: There is for me, i'll post a screenshot

Comment: Rory is most likely on the right track - post the order in which you import your js files.

Comment: right...so the error you posted in your screenshot is **not** the one in the question title. Why did you say the error was something completely different to what it actually is?? `$ is not defined` means very specifically jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: it is..? "ReferenceError: showExpanded is not defined"

Comment: `showExpanded is not defined` != `$ is not defined`. Please try and be as accurate as possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, i wanted it to be general.

Comment: general is rarely much use in programming. Problems like this tend to be specific. Re: your confusion over when to use document.ready(). In general, standalone functions like the ones you've got can be declared outside document.ready, as long as you declare them before they need to be used. If you'd used unobtrusive event handlers though, e.g. `$(p).click(function()...` etc, they definitely need to be within document.ready, otherwise they try to attach to elements that don't exist when the code runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you're missing the `()` after the function names in the `onclick` attributes, for example:

```
<p onclick="removeExpanded()">Remove expanded</p>
```

The functions will also need to be declared in the scope of the `window`, so you'll need to move them outside the document.ready event handler.

However, you shouldn't be using the outdated `on*` event attributes at all. You should be using unobtrusive event handlers instead. As you're using jQuery already, you can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-expanded').click(function() {
    $('#expandSearch').show()
    $('#easySearch').hide();
  });

  $('.remove-expanded').click(function() {
    $('#expandSearch').hide()
    $('#easySearch').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#expandSearch { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="easySearch">
  easySearch
  <p class="show-expanded">Show expanded</p>
</div>
<div id="expandSearch">
  expandSearch
  <p class="remove-expanded">Remove expanded</p>
</div>
```

Also note the use of CSS to hide the `#expandSearch` element on load. This is executed before JS runs, so it will avoid any FOUC.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `()` in the `onclick` attribute:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="easySearch">
  easySearch
  <p onclick="showExpanded()">Show expanded</p>
</div>
<div id="expandSearch">
  expandSearch
  <p onclick="removeExpanded()">Remove expanded</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I did, still reference errror that $showExpanded isn't defined

Comment: as Rory McCrossan said: The functions will also need to be declared in the scope of the window, so you'll need to move them outside the `document.ready` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the functions outside the `document.ready` and use `()` with `onclick`

```js
function showExpanded(){
    $('#expandSearch').css('display', 'block');
    $('#easySearch').css('display', 'none');
  }

  function removeExpanded(){
    $('#expandSearch').css('display', 'none');
    $('#easySearch').css('display', 'block');
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#expandSearch').css('display', 'none');
  $('#easySearch').css('display', 'block');

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="easySearch">
  easySearch
  <p onclick="showExpanded()">Show expanded</p>
</div>
<div id="expandSearch">
  expandSearch
  <p onclick="removeExpanded()">Remove expanded</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can move the event declarations as well as the event handlers to the JavaScript code in a cleaner way:

```js
var $search = $('#easySearch, #expandSearch');

$search.find('p.expander').on('click', function () {
  $search.toggle();
});
```

```css
#expandSearch {display: none;}
p.expander {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="easySearch">
  easySearch
  <p class="expander">Show expanded</p>
</div>
<div id="expandSearch">
  expandSearch
  <p class="expander">Remove expanded</p>
</div>
```